# $\frac{1}{1-x}$ series expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, taylor-expansion

How do I know that the expression:

$$\frac{1}{1-x}$$

Is equal to the infinite sum:

$$-\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^2-\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^3-\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^4+...$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1-x}
=
&
\frac{1}{x\left[\frac{1}{x}-1\right]}
\\
=
&
-\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\frac{1}{1-\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}
\\
=
&
-\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\left[ 1+\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^1+\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^3+\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^4+\cdots\right]
\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 5):

If $|x^{-1}|<1$ then the sum of geometric series:
$$-\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{-n}=-\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{1-x^{-1}}=\frac{1}{1-x}$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: If I were you, I would try to divide $1$ by $1-x$. This is an elementary way to find those terms.

Comment: Good suggestion, Babak!